# what's the difference between proxy and repository pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

repository pattern, heavily used in Entity Framework, which is a class has a repository field(normally injected by DI), so whatever you do save, delete,update a record, you let the repository instance do it like

```
_repository.delete("someID");
```

so isn't that the same thing that proxy pattern try to achieve? In proxy pattern, you also have a proxy instance, and let this instance does the job for you.

so what's the difference between proxy and repository pattern

Comment: Repository is always about talking to your storage. Proxy is a wrapper over any instance that does something extra (like checking who calls the method or creating additional debug logs), nothing related to a storage. The purpose of the two is totally different. Also, means that are used are different.

Comment: @WiktorZychla  Thanks for your answer. isn't that the underlying mechanism is the same, as they all delegate responsibilities to others? so can I say Repository is Proxy that only related to storage?

Comment: Repository is not a Proxy. You definitely need to read about other proxy types (virtual proxy, logging proxy, remote proxy).

Answer (score 2):

While Repository is a class that mediates between business layer and data sources, a proxy is a class that allows for object level access control by acting as a pass through entity or a placeholder object, at any layer you need it.

Answer (score 1):

**Repository** patern is separation of concerns. You can have multiple datasources like memory, sql database, nosql database, webservice ... .

So in big systems is need to use multiple different datasources working different way. And repository is layer which is hiding those sources and propagate only seamless interface without of dependecy on repositories what is good in case of switching some datasource or testing.

[image]

**Proxy** is object pattern. Entity framework is using proxy pattern to achieve som additional functionality. You can switch it off.

`dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

You can be sure that object you get from EF is proxy object full of code. And your `new YOurEntity()` is shallow without proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Repository abstract data layer with collection like interface, so it's not really a design patter as defined in the books. 
Proxy is a design pattern, it allows to control the access to an object and even add functionnality.

That said, there is no real comparision between both, we can even use proxy (or other) patters when implementing Repository.